# Rename or Arrange Pivot Columns in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to arrang or rename pivot columns which are derived from pivot key function without defining key.

my pivot column is `indicator` but i want all unique values in `indicator` `column` to `separate columns` without predefing values by keeping `value` option empty.

if not possible whats best way in one pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **pivot transformation** to create multiple columns from the unique row values of a single column. Pivot is an aggregation transformation where you select group by columns and generate pivot columns using aggregate functions.

Please follow this official tutorial document [Pivot transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot) for the same.